# Symfony3: Doctrine batch processing with exceptions handling

Tags: exception, doctrine, symfony, batch-processing, flush

I need to insert multiple user from an Excel file using Symfony3 command. I have read the following article about batch processing: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html

I have been wondering if there is a way to no stop the flushing process when a query fails (for a not null column for instance). I would actually like to be able to not check all my data before doing the persist and let Doctrine continue the inserts, even though a query failed in the flush of 20 queries lets say.

Thank you for your help.

Kind regards,

Comment: Basically no.  A constraint violation basically means you can no longer use the entity manager.  There has been some talk about changing this but nothing yet.  So upon encountering an exception your only choice would be to make a brand new entity manager object.  The ORM is not really setup for batch processing.  A different approach would be to use the Doctrine Database Abstraction Layer (DBAL).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I assume my options are either to validate everything before flushing, or use one flush per entity and instantiate a new entity manager everytime it fails. Right? What would be wrong in using a flush per entity if I have 2000 entries to store in a row? Thank you

Comment: Nothing wrong with flushing after each entity though you may run into performance issues.  But 2K entities should be fine.  20K maybe not so much.  And yes, validating before trying to persist is probably worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

This template may help you go further...

```
$batchSize = 20;
$currentSize = 0;

$data = [ .... ];
foreach ($data as $item) {
    $entity = new Entity();
    $entity->setProperty($item['property']);

    try {
        $currentSize++;
        $em->persist($entity);

        if ($batchSize% $currentSize === 0) {
            $em->flush();
            $em->clear();
        }
    } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\ORMException $e) {
        $currentSize--;
    }
}

$em->flush();
$em->clear();
```

Comment: Thank you. But doesn't seem like this will tell me which entity failed. Also, if one entity fails to flush, the whole batch fails right?

Comment: As I said, it's just template. If you want to know which entity causing fail(s), you can add $failedEntities = []; above the loop and add $failedEntities[] = $entity; inside the catch. Add $container->get('doctrine')->resetManager(); $em = $container->get('doctrine')->getManager() inside catch to recreate a brand new $em after a fail is caught.